# Problema para calcular el precio de un producto con input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, razor

Tengo una tabla dinámica, por cada fila que se va generando se crea un `<input type="number" onclick="Total();" class="input-number"/>`. Lo que intento hacer es que cuando el usuario aumente o disminuya la cantidad desde el `input number` de la fila elegida, el precio de la columna "Total" vaya cambiando. El problema que tengo es que cuando hago el click en el `input number` de cualquier fila ,aparece como resultado  "NaN" en todas las columnas Total .

Aquí la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la tabla dinámica y jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Total() {

            var price = $('.price').val();
            var quantity = $('.input-number').val();
            var result = price * quantity;
            
            $('.total').val(result);
                       
        }

    </script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-primary table-bordered" id="tableComprar">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Imagen</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
                            <th class="text-center">P/unidad</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                        @foreach (Libro item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center"><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                                <th class="text-center">@item.Nombre</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="price" value="@item.Precio" disabled /></th>
                                <th class="text-center">                   
                                    <input type="number" onchange="Total(this);" class="input-number" value="" min="1" max="@item.Cantidad" placeholder="1"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="total" value="@item.Precio" disabled /></th>                        
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: Prueba enlanzando el cálculo total, al evento `onChange` de tu input number

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera, lo cambie al evento onChange y me sigue apareciendo NaN.

Comment: Los esta leyendo probablemente como *strings* entonces prueba asi: `var result = Number(price) * Number(quantity);`

Comment: gracias @BetaM hice el cambio que dijiste, pero sigo obteniendo como resultado NaN en todas las columnas Total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias compañeros por su aporte!!, siguiendo sus ideas lo resolví de esta manera:

1) Cree una variable contador "idRow" que me sirva como id para cada fila. a cada `input` le asigne un id concatenado con la idRow(logrando para cada input un id diferente).

2) Ademas en la función total() cambie al evento onchange() y le paso por parámetro el idRow.

Muestra de como quedaron los input:

```html
<input type="text" class="price" id="price-@idRow" value="@item.Precio" disabled />
                  
<input type="number" onchange="Total(@idRow);" class="input-number" id="input-number-@idRow" value="1" min="1" max="@item.Cantidad" placeholder="1"/>

<input type="text" class="total" id="total-@idRow" value="@item.Precio" disabled />
```

Aca paso el código html:

```html
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UsserLayout.cshtml";   
    int idRow = 0;
}

<table class="table table-striped table-primary table-bordered" id="tableComprar">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Imagen</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
                            <th class="text-center">P/unidad</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (Libro item in Model)
                        {

                            idRow++;
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center"><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                                <th class="text-center">@item.Nombre</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="price" id="price-@idRow" value="@item.Precio" disabled /></th>
                                <th class="text-center">                   
                                    <input type="number" onchange="Total(@idRow);" class="input-number" id="input-number-@idRow" value="1" min="1" max="@item.Cantidad" placeholder="1"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="total" id="total-@idRow" value="@item.Precio" disabled /></th>                        
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Aca jquery

```js
function Total(idRow) {
        //Hay precios que son float en la bd, para que no de errores siempre convierto a float
         
        var price = parseFloat($("#price-" + idRow).val());
        var quantity = $("#input-number-" + idRow).val();
        var result = parseFloat(price * quantity);

        $("#total-" + idRow).val(result.toFixed(2));//.toFixed(2) muestre 2 decimales despues de la coma
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira este codigo lo hice con una función sencilla:

```html
 <table>

 <tr>
   <th class="text-center"><img src="" width="80" height="100" /></th>
   <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
   <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="price" id="price1" value="10" disabled /></th>
   <th class="text-center">
     <input type="number" onclick="Total(1);" id="cant1" class="input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10" />
   </th>
   <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="total" value="" id="tot1" disabled /></th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="text-center"><img src="" width="80" height="100" /></th>
   <th class="text-center">Nombre 2</th>
   <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="price" id="price2" value="10" disabled /></th>
   <th class="text-center">
     <input type="number" onclick="Total(2);" id="cant2" class="input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10" />
   </th>
   <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="total" value="" id="tot2" disabled /></th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```js
    function Total(id){
          $("#tot"+id).val($("#cant"+id).val()*$("#price"+id).val());
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que estas tomando todos los inputs con clase "price", al hacer esto obtienes un array, y lo multiplicas con otro array de "cantidadades", asi que podrias generar un id por cada input.

Comment: Agrega aquí tu código amigo la plataforma soporta ejecución de html, css y js

Comment: Gracias @HERRERA bienvenido!, voy a aplicar tu forma, de todas maneras acabo de subir el html y javascript juntos para que se pueda ejecutar y ver el error.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comenté, enlance el evento **[onChange](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** al `input-number`, debido a que al momento de realizar los cambios en la cantidad estos no se reflejaban en el total.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let unit = $('#price').val()
  let quantity = $('#quantity').val()
  let total = calculate(unit, quantity)
  $('#total').val(total)
  
  $('#quantity').on('change', () => {
    unit = $('#price').val()
    quantity = $('#quantity').val()
    total = calculate(unit, quantity)
    $('#total').val(total)  
  })
  
  function calculate(price, quantity) {
    return price * quantity
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-primary table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Imagen</th>
      <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
      <th class="text-center">P/unidad</th>
      <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="text-center">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center"><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
      <th class="text-center">@item.Nombre</th>
      <th class="text-center"><input type="text" class="price" id="price" value="22" disabled /></th>
      <th class="text-center">                   
        <input type="number" id="quantity" class="input-number" value="13" min="1" max="@item.Cantidad" placeholder="1"/>
      </th>
      <th class="text-center"><input type="text" id="total" class="total" disabled /></th>                        
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Debes incluir un `id` en cada `input` para que puedas realizar el cálculo por fila; si lo haces por clases - como esta actualmente -, al cambiar un valor en el *input-number*, se actualizarán todos los totales de la tabla. Puedes concatenar un nombre genérico más el índice del elemento dentro de tu `for` para solucionar esto ;)

Nos comentas como te va =)

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera por tu aporte!